# Many-to-many relationship, what's the best choice for primary key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key, many-to-many, relations

In advance, I'd like to apologize if it's a duplicate question... I can't find a direct answer, probably because I'm not a native english speaker.

Straight to the subject:

I have 2 tables: **company**, which contains some companies (of course) and **service**, which contains general services that can be provided by the companies. Now I need to create another table in order to build the link between company and service, since it's a many-to-many relationship.

Which is the best choice for primary key in this case (considering conventions and performance)?

**- like this, making use of an "independent" unique field `id`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`company_service` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `service_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

or

**- like this, with the two fields that represents the foreign keys composing the primary key?**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`company_service` (
  `company_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `service_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`, `service_id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

... or none of these, maybe a third design?

My working environment is MySQL.

Comment: A separate ID column adds overhead, and I cannot see any reason why it would be useful. So you should go with the second option. An you will likely need an index on service_id, too. Also consider using InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: I'd use the second option, with the composite PK. Also, ditto on using InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: Use the second option _and_ change to InnoDB.  [_Details_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: It went to the second option and InnoDB. Thanks a lot everyone.